# Access a Zend application from another computer in the LAN (working with LAMP)

Tags: php, zend-framework, lamp, lan, virtual-hosts

Hello I have a LAMP server setup on an Ubuntu machine and a Zend Framework project.

I made a virtual host in my /etc/apache2/sites-available, enabled it with a2ensite command and everything works great on localhost but I have a problem accessing the application from another computer in my LAN using my IP

If I go to 192.168.x.x/application_name/public (that is where the index.php is) i get the folder listing.

PS: phpmyadmin works (192.168.x.x/phpmyadmin)

Am I missing some configurations?

My virtual host

`<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin xx@localhost

    ServerName application.local

    ServerAlias www.application.local

    DirectoryIndex index.php

    DocumentRoot /var/www/application/public/

</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Do you have an `index.php` file in the directory? Also your virtual host requires you to access it using the name(s) configured in `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` - accessing it by IP won't work unless you add that IP address to the `ServerAlias` directive, which you probably don't want to do. You can create an entry in your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) if you don't have it configure in internal DNS.

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea. I put the IP address at the ServerAlias and it works. Of course if I have another application in my /var/www/ folder it cannot be accessed but it's no problem so far. I only wanted to test the app from more computers at one time. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is edit the hosts file on the 2nd machine to add an entry for

```
192.168.x.x    application.local
```

where 192.168.x.x is the IP address of the machine with the app on, and application.local matches the value in the ServerName of your vhost. Then just open a browser and go to http://application.local/